# Unique Equivariant Symplectic Structure for the Full Flag Manifold of $SU(3)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

I was looking at the following interesting [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215067/equivariant-almost-complex-structures-on-the-full-flag-manifolds) about the number of equivariant almost complex structures on the full flag manifold of $SU(3)$, and I began to wonder how many equivariant symplectic structures there are on the same space, i.e.  $M := SU(3)/T^2$. Now as I understand it, there is a unique equivariant  K\"ahler metric for $M$, which will of course  give us one equivariant symplectic  structure, and since symplectic structures which do not arise from K\"ahler metrics are hard to come by, I would conjecture that this is the only equivariant symplectic structure for this space. Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ acts on $M$ (both compact and finite-dimensional) preserving the symplectic form, and $M$ is simply-connected, the action is Hamiltonian. Then $M$ maps symplectomorphically to a coadjoint orbit of $G$. This gives a $rank(G)$-dimensional family of symplectic forms, not a unique one.

You should consider the $SU(2)$ case first, where $\mathbb{CP}^1$ doesn't have a unique area form (or area).

Comment: I guess there is some misunderstanding here, when I said unique, I intended "unique up to scalar multiple". I thought this was obvious . . . but obviously not. Apologies for my sloppiness.

Comment: For $SU(3)$, does the 2-dim space of symplectic forms imply another equivariant Hermitian metric?

Comment: Yes, there is a $[0,1]$ interval's worth of invariant (I don't know why you say equivariant) Hermitian metrics, considered up to scale.